# Kafka: auto create topic with options

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic

I'm using auto-creation of topics in Kafka. Some topics require compaction, some not.

Is it possible to specify custom options when auto-creating a topic; or do I need to test for existence and create it 'manually' with the desired options before I consume or produce on it?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling auto creation of topics allow you to write to a topic that does not exists. The only thing that you can define in your KafkaProducer is the *name* of the topic.

All configurations for that topic will be set according to your default settings for topics, also called *Server Default Property*.

In the documentation on the [Topic Configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html) you will find the corresponding configuration names, for example the Server Default Property for topic config`cleanup.policy` is broker config `log.cleanup.policy`.

In case you need full control of checking for the existence of a topic and create it with specific configuration programatically, you can make use of the [AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html).